# SASS error in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I use SASS for bootstrap 4

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .some-class {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

and getting error

```
Error: Undefined mixin 'media-breakpoint-up'.
        on line 1 of sass/main.scss, in `media-breakpoint-up'
        from line 1 of sass/main.scss
```

Does anyone knows why?

I have included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you include bootstrap mixin file ?

Comment: I have included <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: dude i think u need to learn sass first

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your [mixin](http://sass-lang.com/guide) incorrectly. It should look something like below.

```
@mixin media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .some-class {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

If you want to use that call it as below:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm-value);
```

I see that you are not using your input `sm`.